# How to positively interact with mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Sometimes, I would be a Minecraft server pacifist, but what about a Singleplayer one? Well, to accomplish this, I have to:

- Not hurt or kill any mobs whatsoever
- Find resources without hurting them
- Contributely positively towards them, like giving them a better life

So if I want to positively interact with the mobs, what can I do with them?

Comment: I have fixed the "details or clarity" bit.

Comment: by "*Contribute* positively towards them, like giving them a better life" do implied(or indirect) positive impacts count? or only direct and clear interactions

Comment: Depends on the context of "positive". Any positive aspects or interactions are acceptable. Also, the answer is CW, so anyone can edit the answer.

Comment: so, for example "planting flowers near a bee(hive)" would count as positive for a bee, and other things like that would count.

Comment: @Topcode Yep, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Order from the Bedrock Edition inventory.

- **Sea Turtle:** You can get them to breed via seagrass, making them produce their eggs.
- **Chicken:** You can get them to breed via seeds.
- **Bee:** You can place flowers near them/their hive
- **Cow:** You can get them to breed via wheat.
- **Pig:** You can get them to breed via potato or carrot, and you can ride on them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Sheep:** You can get them to breed via wheat, and you can shear them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Wolf:** You can get them to breed via meat and tame them for help.
- **Polar Bear:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Ocelot:** You can get them to breed via fish (except pufferfish), and tame them for help.
- **Cat:** You can get them to breed via fish (except pufferfish), and tame them for help.
- **Mooshroom:** You can breed them via wheat, and you can shear them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Bat:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Parrot:** You can get them to breed via seeds, and you can tame them for fun.
- **Rabbit:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Llama:** You can get them to breed via hay bales, and you can ride on them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Horse:** You can get them to breed via wheat, and you can ride on them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Donkey:** You can get them to breed via wheat, and you can ride on them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Mule:** You can get them to breed via wheat, and you can ride on them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Skeleton Horse:** You can ride on them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Zombie Horse:** You can ride them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Tropical Fish:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Cod:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Pufferfish:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Salmon:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Dolphin:** Give them some food and they can give you treasure.
- **Panda:** You can get them to breed via bamboo.
- **Fox:** You can get them to breed.
- **Creeper:**  (No given interaction yet.)
- **Enderman:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Silverfish:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Skeleton:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Wither Skeleton:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Stray:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Slime:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Spider:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Zombie:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Zombified Piglin:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Husk:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Drowned:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Squid:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Cave Spider:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Witch:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Guardian:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Elder Guardian:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Endermite:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Magma Cube:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Strider:** You can get them to breed via warped fungus, and you can ride on them<sup>[1]</sup>.
- **Hoglin:** You can get them to breed via crimson fungus.
- **Piglin:** You can barter with them, dropping certain items.
- **Zoglin:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Piglin Brute:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Ghast:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Blaze:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Shulker:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Vindicator:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Evoker:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Vex:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Villager:** Win a raid<sup>[2]</sup>, then get better trades.
- **Wandering Trader:** You can trade with them.
- **Zombie Villager:** Can be cured and useful for trades.
- **Phantom:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Pillager:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Ravager:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Iron Golem:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Snow Golem:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Wither:** (No given interaction yet.)
- **Ender Dragon:** (No given interaction yet.)

> **Notes:**
>
> <sup>**[1]**</sup> They won't really get hurt, because they don't have actual emotions, other than the hit sounds.
>
> <sup>**[2]**</sup> Technically no longer pacifist, as you interfered negatively with another mob.